How do I dynamically alter the speed of a GraphicObject in Incisor?
I am attempting to dynamically alter the speed of a GraphicObject in motion in Incisor. I have a speed property initialized to zero. I add motion, using the speed property as my motion speed. Then, I swoop value on the speed property.
Here's a simple example of what I'm doing.
class ProjectMain {


    init() {
     

        let myGraphicObject = new GraphicObject( nc.graphicAssets.whiteBox, nc.mainScene, "Box" );

        this.speed = 0;

        myGraphicObject.position.addMotion.each( [-300,-100,0], [300,100,10], this.speed, nc.motionTypes.MoveInCircle );

    // swoop the speed property to alter the motion
        nc.swoopValue( this, "speed", 10, 10 );
        
    }
}

I expect to see the box increase speed as it spins but it is actually not moving at all. I am obviously doing something wrong here. My assumption is that the speed is initialized to zero, and swooping it is having no effect on the motion. So, the motion is zero. No movement.
How can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Great question! You're on the right track by using nc.swoopValue() — that's the correct approach. The only issue is that you're swooping the wrong property.
Remember, the addMotion.each() function returns a motion instance, which you can use to control various motion properties. For example:
let motion = myGraphicObject.position.addMotion.each( [-300,-100,0], [300,100,10], 0, nc.motionTypes.MoveInCircle );

To dynamically change the motion speed, you need to swoop the motionSpeed property of the motion instance, not the position.
Here’s the corrected code to achieve what you're aiming for:
let myGraphicObject = new GraphicObject( nc.graphicAssets.whiteBox, nc.mainScene, "Box" );

let motion = myGraphicObject.position.addMotion.each( [-300,-100,0], [300,100,10], 0, nc.motionTypes.MoveInCircle );

// swoop the "motionSpeed" property of the "motion" instance to alter the motion
nc.swoopValue( motion, "motionSpeed", 10, 10 );

This will smoothly change the speed of the motion over the specified duration. Let me know if you need further clarification!
